# How to typeset longer $\Rightarrow$ with text under it using MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I don't know how to typeset the $\Rightarrow$ with the text under it  as shown in this image? I know that \xrightarrow{\text{substitution}} gives rise to $\xrightarrow{\text{substitution}}$ but when changing the r with R I get an error. Furthermore, how to make the text appear under the arrow?

[image: Blockquote]

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the (non-standard) `\Newextarrow` command from the extpfeil extension to define `\xRightarrow`:

```
$\require{extpfeil}\Newextarrow{\xRightarrow}{5,5}{0x21D2}$
$\xRightarrow[\text{text below}]{}$
```

which produces 
$\require{extpfeil}\Newextarrow{\xRightarrow}{5,5}{0x21D2}$
$\xRightarrow[\text{text below}]{}$

Perhaps that will work for you.

Comment: +1: Many thanks! $\text{}$

Comment: For completeness, the "above" version: `$\xRightarrow[\text{below}]{\text{above}}$`. Testing:  $\require{extpfeil}\Newextarrow{\xRightarrow}{5,5}{0x21D2}$ $\xRightarrow[\text{below}]{\text{above}}$

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find a way to extend the double arrow in MathJax, but you can get text underneath as an optional argument

`A\xrightarrow[\text{under the arrow}]{\text{above the arrow}}B`
$$
A\xrightarrow[\text{under the arrow}]{\text{above the arrow}}B
$$
I think that if MathJax had an option to use [mathtools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103994), we could use `\xRightarrow`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful @robjohn !

Answer (score 1):

This won't extend the arrow, but you can use `\overset` and `\underset` on, say, `\Longrightarrow`.  You might also want to look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85115) in tex.SE, but it probably won't work on SE itself.